# Printing out 2d array elements in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out elements in a 2d array, but can't seem to format it. Anytime I try to format it I get an error

```
    String [][] plants = new String[2][2];
    plants[0][0] = "Rose";
    plants[0][1] = "Red";
    plants[1][0] = "Snowdrop";
    plants[1][1] = "White";

    //String plant;
    //String color;
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<2; j++){

        //plant = Arrays.toString(plants[i]);
        //color = Arrays.deepToString(plants[j]);
        //System.out.println(plant + " " + color);
        System.out.println(plants[i][j]);

    }
    }
```

What I have so far prints out each element on an individual line, but I want it to print out like:

Rose Red

Snowdrop White

I've tried the methods commented out, but they won't work right either.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please tell us what the error is

Comment: I have an idea. What if noone flags any duplicate answers cause we wrote it quite in the same time and the author asking a question will do us a favor by upvoting them? :D #myRepNeedsToGrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the inner loop do `System.out.print(plants[i][j] + " ");`

In the outer loop do `System.out.println();`

Answer (score 4):

Your for-loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < plants.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < plants[i].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(plants[i][j]);
        if(j < plants[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Works for any String[][]. But I would print "\t" instead of " " between the elements. This makes much nicer formatting especially if your String [][] can contain empty Strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
    System.out.println(plants[i][0] + " " + plants[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: Hey Simon I need rep more than you do :'( :D :| Anyways hi5 for same answer, zzz :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){  

        System.out.println(plants[i][0] + " " + plants[i][1]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<2; j++){

        System.out.print(plants[i][j]);

    }
     System.out.println();
}
```

However you are better off using for each to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++)
{
    System.out.println(plants[i][0] + ' ' + plants[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: So is `String [][] plants = new String[2][2];`

Comment: Given the question, the OP might not want something too complicated to start with, that was my idea.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with the `System.out.println(plants[i][j]);`
After printing a String "Rose" it will automatically go to next Line....
you can use simple `print` in inside block instead of `println` which would keep cursor in same line instead of going to next Line...

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    { 
        System.out.print(plants[i][j]);    
    }  
    System.out.println();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    System.out.println(plants[i][0] + " " + plants[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop you should use

System.out.print(plants[i][j]);

And in  the outer loop you should use 
System.out.println();